# How do I display specific data in a chart from access database?

Tags: database, vb.net, forms, ms-access, charts

I currently have an access database with a table which stores items bought by each customer and the quantity of the item that's bought. So multiple customers can buy the same item with different quantities. I want to display the total quantity bought by all customers for each item and display it in a chart on Vb.net Form. This is what I have so far. When I run this it shows the repeated data in my table for quantity, when I want it to add all the quantities together to display one value single value for each item. There is a way to do this? I've researched this a lot and I can't seem to find a way to do this. Do I have to query the database first so it selects the quantity of each item, adds it together and then displays it in the chart? if so how do I do this?

Thanks a lot!

```
Me.OrderItemTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.POS_system1DataSet5.OrderItem)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'POS_system1DataSet3.OrderItem' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.OrderItemTableAdapter.Fill(Me.POS_system1DataSet3.OrderItem)


        OrdersGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Interval = 1
        ' Axis X
        OrdersGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.TitleFont = New Font("Oswald", 18.0F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        OrdersGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Title = "Menu Items"
        ' Axis Y
        OrdersGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.TitleFont = New Font("Oswald", 18.0F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        OrdersGraph.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Title = "Quantity"

        'Hide legend label
        OrdersGraph.Series("Orders").IsVisibleInLegend = False

        'Show number value in bar / column chart
        OrdersGraph.Series("Orders").IsValueShownAsLabel = True

        ' value member
        OrdersGraph.Series("Orders").XValueMember = "ItemID"
        OrdersGraph.Series("Orders").YValueMembers = "Quantity"
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not really with the chart. It is how to select the data you need from your datasource. So I guess when you select, you have some properties which correspond to the table. I made a class which can represent that. For testing

```vb
Public Class OrderItem
    Public Property ItemID As Integer
    Public Property OrderNo As Integer
    Public Property Quantity As Integer
    Public Property OrderID As Integer

    Public Sub New(itemID As Integer, orderNo As Integer, quantity As Integer, orderID As Integer)
        Me.ItemID = itemID
        Me.OrderNo = orderNo
        Me.Quantity = quantity
        Me.OrderID = orderID
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then I added the data in your table to a list of that class

```vb
Dim orderItems As New List(Of OrderItem)()
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(3, 84118, 33, 3))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(6, 63940, 4, 16))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(6, 77996, 6, 17))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(5, 77996, 8, 18))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(8, 48475, 3, 21))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(13, 48475, 2, 22))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(2, 93914, 4, 25))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(6, 93914, 4, 26))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(5, 77590, 5, 31))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(2, 93946, 4, 32))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(6, 93946, 3, 33))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(2, 89181, 4, 38))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(6, 89181, 4, 39))
orderItems.Add(New OrderItem(3, 98014, 4, 40))
```

Now the important part, grouping the data by the ItemID and taking the count of items. You can use LINQ for this

```vb
Dim groupedOrderItems = orderItems.GroupBy(Function(oi) oi.ItemID).Select(Function(oig) New With {oig.Key, oig.Count()})
```

And applying the dataset to the chart

```
OrdersGraph.Series("Orders").Points.DataBindXY(
    groupedOrderItems.Select(Function(oig) oig.Key).ToArray(),
    groupedOrderItems.Select(Function(oig) oig.Count).ToArray())
```

[image]